# What happens if dynamic array index is out of range?

Tags: arrays

What happens in a function where user can supply an uint256 which reads the data from a dynamic array... What happens if index is out of range?
Does transaction revert automatically?
Or do i have to implement additional check: `require(myDynamicArray.length > proposalID)` ?

```
  function doSomething(uint256 proposalID) {
      if(myDynamicArray[proposalID].isActivated) {
//blah blah do something
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The transaction will revert. If I remember right, the execution emits a *panic code* which reverts everything. But, regardless of how the revertion is triggered, the execution will revert.